# Gradiant fill custom drawing in C++ Builder XE

Tags: delphi, colors, c++builder, gradient, c++builder-xe

I have drawn a custom drawing in C++ Builder XE with the help of the code below, but now I want to fill it with gradientfill color.

```cpp
PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color = RGB (187, 187, 187);

PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(0, 8);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(10, 0);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(10, 5);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(21, 5);
PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(0, 8);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(10, 15);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(10, 10);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(21, 10);
PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(21, 5);
```

Comment: This is rather easy. Either you do it yourself using the `Scanline` property (and, for God's sake, let me be extra clear on this: do **not** use the `Pixels` property!), or you use the GDI+ [`GradientFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144957(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: PaintBox has scanlines, what?

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light: Then `BitBlt` from an off-screen `TBitmap`.

Comment: @Andreas: do it with ScanLine?  Surely implementing your own fill algorithm (if that's what you mean) for this is overkill.  @dschaeffer's suggestion of the GDI GradientFill and clipping the region seems simpler and more reliable, and probably faster, to me.

Comment: @David M: dschaeffer's solution is based on the [`GradientFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144957(VS.85).aspx) function I suggested.

Comment: @Andreas: I thought you wrote about GDI+ (given your link I think that was a typo though.)  I wasn't suggesting either version of a premade fill function was bad, though - I was wondering how rolling your own polygon fill function (which can be complex) was good.... it's interesting and fun to learn, maybe, but I doubt it's a good suggestion for someone who needs a solution only.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easiest to use GradientFillCanvas with a clipping region.  See the folowing links:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GraphUtil.GradientFillCanvas

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/12/324143.html

So you would do something like:

```
POINT polygon[8] = {{0,8},{10,0},{10,5},{21,5},{21,10},{10,10},{10,15},{0,8}};
HRGN rgn = CreatePolygonRgn( polygon, 8, WINDING );
SelectClipRgn(PaintBox1->Canvas.Handle, rgn);
TRect gradientRect(0,0,21,15);
GradientFillCanvas( PaintBox1->Canvas, start_color, end_color, gradientRect, gradient_direction );
SelectClipRgn(PaintBox1->Canvas.Handle, NULL);
DeleteObject(rgn);
//the polygon could also be drawn instead of using LineTo
PaintBox1->Canvas->Polygon( polygon, 8 );
```